# MySQL order by field in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent

When I want to define a custom sort order in a MySQL query I can do something like this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(language,'USD','EUR','JPN')
```

What would be the Eloquent ORM version of that?

**UPDATE:**

This is the solution and it also works when ordering on various fields:

```
$events = Event::with( 'type', 'location' )
               ->orderBy( 'event_type_id' )
               ->orderByRaw( "FIELD(status, 'good', 'bad', 'hidden', 'active', 'cancelled')" )
               ->orderBy( 'date' );
```

Comment: did you try `$query->orderBy("FIELD(language,'USD','EUR','JPN')", 'asc');` ?

Comment: Yes, but that results in an "unknown field" error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using either `DB::raw()` or `orderByRaw` directly should work:

```
$models = Model::orderByRaw('FIELD(language, "USD", "EUR", "JPN")')->get();
// or
$models = Model::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(language, "USD", "EUR", "JPN")'))->get();
```

Comment: Aside from the raw order query I am also ordering on other fields. So I get this error now: ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asc' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `events` where `events`.`deleted_at` is null and `status` = 'good' order by `event_type_id` asc, FIELD(status, 'good', 'bad', 'hidden', 'active', 'cancelled', `date` asc)```

Comment: Looks like you put `asc` inside the parenthesis

Comment: I updated the initial question to include the Eloquent syntax.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it seems like I forgot to add the closing parenthesis. Thanks for your answer. It works now.

Comment: If in your case still doesn't work, try using the notation **table_name.field_name** (in this case «events.language» instead of only «language») as if there are repeated field names with other linked tables, it can give problems

Comment: Is this limiting the results or just ordering them? If I order by something - lets say an id and I order by 2, 5, 7 - what will happen with the rest of the rows which have different ids?

Answer (score 11):

Use **implode** in the second parameter of FIELD()

```
 $facilities = $query->with(['interest','city:id,name', 'state:id,name'])
        ->Active()
        ->whereIn('facility_id', $facilities_list)
        ->orderByRaw('FIELD(facility_id, '.implode(", " , $facilities_list).')')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using join you can simplay add table name before column.

```
Student::orderByRaw('FIELD(students.id, 3, 2, 1) DESC')->join('students_contact', 'students_contact.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
->get();
```

Note:
Start adding a column in the raw query by the right side, let me explain with an example
If you want to achieve the orders 7, 8, 9

```
orderByRaw('FIELD(students.id, 9, 8, 7) DESC')
```

Then it will fetch the data in the correct way. I also added the DESC keyword becuase it adds sorted data at the bottom of the list, not at starting of the list.