# Sort collection by custom order in Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of ID's as follows:

```
$ids = [5,6,0,1]
```

Using Eloquent I am able to search for these Id's using the `->whereIn('id', $ids)` function. This as expected will return the results in the ascending order by Id,  is there a way I can return the results on the order the array is in? alternatively whats the easiest way to convert the collection in the order of the `$ids` array?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If there's a specific order you'd like the records in, you'd have to use the [Collection Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods):

To get your ID's in the very specific order you've specified, you can make use of the `sortBy` method as follows, where collection is your collection of models:

```
$ids = [ 5, 6, 0, 1];

$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($model) use ($ids) {
    return array_search($model->getKey(), $ids);
});

// [ 5, 6, 0, 1] // (desired order)
```

To randomize your collection you can make use of the `shuffle` method.

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$shuffled = $collection->shuffle();

$shuffled->all();

// [3, 2, 5, 1, 4] // (generated randomly)
```

See the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods) on `shuffle` and/or `sortBy` for more specific requirements.

If you don't really have a specific order in mind, you can use `->inRandomOrder()` in version 5.2 and up, older versions would require the raw query using `->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))`.

Answer (score 12):

See answer to [MySQL order by field in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659430/mysql-order-by-field-in-eloquent). It is possible to order the data in your SQL query. Other answers here are suggesting you sort the data after you've already fetched it in "wrong" order.

Your code should look like this:

```
$ids = [5,6,0,1];

$collection = YourModel::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, ' . implode(', ', $ids) . ') ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Note: this could open you up to SQL injection attacks if `$ids` was user-supplied data which had not been properly escaped.

Comment: Is there a Postgres version? Since FIELD isn't available there.

Comment: Possible option for postgres:
->orderByRaw("CASE
                  WHEN status = 1 THEN 3
                  WHEN status = 2 THEN 2
                  ELSE 1 END")

Answer (score -2):

You can pass a function into the sortBy method to perform complex sorting:

```
$ids = [5,6,0,1];

$collection = YourModel::whereIn('id', $ids)->sortBy(function($model) use ($ids) {
    // Access your array order here and modify the sorting here
});
```

Comment: This does not work, as Model::whereIn() does not return a collection but a query builder object. To work there should be a ->get() call between whereIn and sortBy