# Laravel: How to get custom sorted eloquent collection using whereIn method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have an array of product ids against which I need to retrieve the model collection. The array is something like this:

```
$ids = array(9, 2, 16, 11, 8, 1, 18);
```

Right now, I'm using the following line of code to get the collection.

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

But it sorts the products against their ids. such as: `1, 2, 8, 9, 11, 16, 18`. What I need is the same order as in the `$ids` array i.e `9, 2, 16, 11, 8, 1, 18`.

What should I do to get the same order as in the array?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I'd say that's more of a custom sort than unsorted, though.

Comment: I think I found a duplicate for it based on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731863/sort-collection-by-custom-order-in-eloquent

Comment: I don't want to close your question as duplicate of that one yet because I'm not 100% sure that's what you want. Does the answer there solve your problem?

Comment: I believe the duplicate candidate answers the question. However, Khalid's answer on this one is much more interesting. @Don'tPanic

Comment: Yes, the linked solution is great and working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Field()` function of mysql (If you are using mysql database) with `DB::raw()` of laravel something like

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("FIELD(id,".join(',',$ids).")"))
    ->get();
```

> [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the index position of a comma-delimited list

Comment: Oh, that's a clever way to do it. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Great! it's an interesting and cleaner approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do that.

```
$ids = array(9, 2, 16, 11, 8, 1, 18);
$products = User::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw('FIELD(id, '.implode(',', $ids).')')->get();
```