# codeigniter fetch mysql table with where_in + keep order of key array in result array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a string with image ids (fetched from another mysql table)
and converted to an array:

```
$idstring = "12, 18, 3, 392, 0, 9, 44";
$idarray = explode(',', $idstring);
```

Based on this array of ids, I want get all the rows from my "media" mysql table.

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')
->from('media')
->where_in('id', $ids)
->get()->result_array();
```

The problem is the `$result` array's values are in a weird order like this:

```
$result's order : 44, 9 ,0 ,18 ,3 ,392 ,12 ...
```

But i need them to stay like in my $id string/array order...

I've tried 4 approaches to solve the issue so far:

1. Fetch rows in a loop without `where_in()` - what creates a lot of queries - but works for now ...
2. Reorder the `$result` array based on the order of the `$idstring` or the `$idarray`, though I could not manage to to find a working result and I don't get the point why this step is necessary at all
3. Try to get the query itself fixed. I've heard about `ORDER_BY` and `FIND_IN_SET`, `$ids` but I could not get it into my a working codeigniter query and don't know about the performance if this is really a help

So in conclusion, I think this should be a simple everyday task, i just want to fetch a bunch of pictures in a given order with codeigniter.

Am I missing a simple solution here?

Answer (score 5):

Use `Field()` function of mysql

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('media')
            ->where_in('id', $ids)
            ->order_by("FIELD(id,".join(',',$ids).")")
            ->get()
            ->result_array()
```

it should be something like

```
FIELD(id,12, 18, 3, 392, 0, 9, 44)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270669/laravel-how-to-get-custom-sorted-eloquent-collection-using-wherein-method/47270768#47270768)

> [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the index position of a comma-delimited list

Comment: `$idstring` can be used instead of `join(',',$idarray)`

Comment: @PhilippMaurer i guess this `"FIELD(id,".$idstring.")"`will work if you want to do with `$idstring`

Comment: thanks alot philipp and m khalid junaid. i got it working - and learned something new. and my gut was right - there must be a simple way:)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer should be **M Khalid Junaid** answer. But just in case, if you are generating  from an array like I do, use it like this:

```php
$filters = [
   "order_by" => [
       "title" => "DESC",
       ""FIELD(id,".join(',',$ids).")" => "" // The option should be empty...
   ]
];

foreach($filters["order_by"] as $attribute => $option){
    $this->db->order_by( $attribute, $option );
}
```

**The output** will be:

```php
...
ORDER BY `name` DESC, FIELD(id, 2017, 2031, 2032, 2034, 2035)
LIMIT 50
```

Just to for clarification.