# Retrieve Laravel Modal data for multiple id

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have an array,I want to find my modal data according to array value.My array looks like

```
$item = [5,3,4,1];
```

I used for find these items

```
$topSell = Product::find($item);
```

It returns data serialize like 1,3,4,5. But I want it will return exact same as my array serialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How to get custom sorted eloquent collection using whereIn method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270669/laravel-how-to-get-custom-sorted-eloquent-collection-using-wherein-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Mysql with laravel you can use `Field()` in order by

```
$topSell = Product::whereIn('id', $item)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("FIELD(id,".join(',',$item).")"))
    ->get();
```

> [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the index position of a comma-delimited list

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270669/laravel-how-to-get-custom-sorted-eloquent-collection-using-wherein-method/47270768#47270768)