# Laravel does not give the values sequentially

Tags: php, laravel

I have a car ids array.

```
$carIds = [21,12,33];
```

I'm sending an ids array to retrieve values from my collection.

```
$cars = Cars::whereIn('id', $carIds)->get();
```

Incoming car values do not come in the order of id I gave, it is complicated.

Comment: Because default sorting in database is done by id. You will have to sort to the wanted order manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintaining order in MySQL "IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631723/maintaining-order-in-mysql-in-query)

Answer (score 0):

update your code with below code

```
Cars::whereIn('id', $carIds)
->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, ' . implode(', ', $carIds) . ') ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: i am getting this error $meta is the only expression supported by $sort right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731863/sort-collection-by-custom-order-in-eloquent

Comment: check this question

Answer (score 0):

Different way you can do is :

```
$cars = DB::table('Cars')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Comment: As the question clearly states that result must be in the order based on user provided ```ids```