# Laravel whereIn incorrect order of result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I want to get record from database when array of ids match the id in the customer table.

Here is my array of ID:

```
0 => 1
1 => 1788
2 => 887
3 => 697
4 => 719
```

I have following query,

```
$customers = Customer::whereIn('id', $idArray)->get();
```

I am getting all the customers I need but not in correct order. I am getting customers in following order.

```
1
697
719
887
1788
```

Is it default behaviour or something I am doing wrong.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you not add an `orderBy`?

Comment: @Jonnix I want the customers as in same order in the array

Comment: Ah right, what's the order rule? Just the order of the $idArray? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values does that help? I don't know how that would translate in Laravel.

Comment: @Jonnix Yes order of id array

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659430/mysql-order-by-field-in-eloquent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `òrderByRaw` query builder method to add a raw "order by" clause to the query.
The method's signature is

```php
$this orderByRaw(string $sql, array $bindings = [])
```

So it expects a raw sql query as an argument, let's give it one using the `DB` facade providing the desired `$ids_ordered` as a string

```php
$idArray = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1788,
    2 => 887,
    3 => 697,
    4 => 719,
];
$ids_ordered = implode(',', $idArray); // Basically casts the array values to a string
$customers = Customer::whereIn('id', $idArray)
                     ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))
                     ->get();
return $customers;
```

The raw sql query would be like (assuming `MySQL` as a DB engine)

```sql
select * from `customers` where `id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) order by FIELD(id, 1,1788,887,697,719)
```

Results:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15"
    },
    {
        "id": 1788,
        "created_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15"
    },
    {
        "id": 887,
        "created_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15"
    },
    {
        "id": 697,
        "created_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15"
    },
    {
        "id": 719,
        "created_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-02 12:21:15"
    }
]
```